# Friday (Jummah) Prayers on a vacation trip

Tags: sharia, salat, jumuah

Assalamu alaikkum everyone!

I just wanted to clarify the doubt that I have as what the title says. Not that I eagerly wanted to join the trip, but I've some official work to complete too.

To make it more clear, our office colleagues are tripping out to one of our island which is under renovation. On the same island, I've some works to be completed by me. Also there is a mosque in the island, but I'm not sure the minimum number of people needed to pray friday prayers with jama'ath. So, I requested another day to visit for the work and said that I will not be joining.

What is the best advise when such instant occurs. Please help me to understand on this more with proofs/reference (if available).

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

> The number of people required for al-jumu'ah (Friday prayer): **There is no dispute among the scholars that a congregation is a necessary condition for the validity of al-jumu'ah (Friday prayer)**. This is based on the hadith of Tariq ibn shihab who reports that the prophet said: "Al-jumu'ah (Friday prayer) is an obligation upon every Muslim in the community."
>
> **However, the scholars do differ on how many people are required for al-jumu'ah (Friday prayer)**. There are fifteen different opinions on this question and they are mentioned by Imam Ibn Hajar in his book "Fath Al-bari" The strongest opinion is that salatul Jumu'ah (Friday prayer) is valid if there are two or more people present since the Prophet is reported to have said: "Two or more constitute a congregation."
>
> Imam Ash-Shaukani says: "The other prayers are considered to be made in congregation if there are two people present. The same applies to jumu'ah salah (Friday prayer), unless there is a reason for it to be different. There is no evidence for show that (for the purpose of the congregation) its number should be larger than that for the other prayers. ' Abudul Haqq says: 'There is no confirmed hadith on the number of people needed for al-jumu'ah (Friday prayer). Similarly, **Imam As-Sayuti holds: 'There is no confirmed hadith which states a particular number (for the jumu'ah salah (Friday prayer)).' "This is also the opinion of Imams At-Tabari, Dawud, an-Nakha'I, and Ibn hazm.**

**salatul Jumu'ah (Friday prayer) is wājib. But a kind of wājib that you can choose to do or to do the alternative (which in this case is dhuhr salah).** But this is true as long as there are people to go and pray the salatul Jumu'ah. If there's not enough people, it's wājib to go.

for more information about salatul Jumu'ah, please read the following links:

- http://islam1.org/khutub/Rules_of_Friday_Prayer_1.htm
- [Why is Jummah Important? (Jumu'ah/ Jumma'h/ Friday)](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7726/why-is-jummah-important-jumuah-jummah-friday)
- [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumu'ah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumu%27ah)

Comment: hm... salat al Jumu'a is fardu 'ayn (Sunni Point of view) this means any muslim (man) except those quoted in a hadith (http://sunnah.com/abudawud/2/678) has to it. The word wajib doesn't point this out!

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, salatul jummah is not wajib for the traveler, which sounds like what you are when you go out to that island.

Comment: I have heard this too, but there might be different of opinions. Would you mind adding references?