# What is the history of Jummah namaz?

Tags: history, islamic-events, jumuah

It is known that we were ordered to pay namaz 5 times a day by ALLAH HIMSELF .

I don't have any references , nor do I have much knowledge

can somebody please help with a little history for Jummah namaz .

When did it started , its meaning and its importance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are the most important services in Islam held on Fridays?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/2790/why-are-the-most-important-services-in-islam-held-on-fridays)

Answer (score 2):

Abdullah b. 'Abbas (ra) narrates from the Prophet (saws) that permission to perform the Friday prayer was given (by Allah) before hijrah, but the people were unable to congregate and perform it. The Prophet (saws) wrote a note to Mus'ab b. Umair (who was deputed to Madinah at the time to instruct them in Islam) to pray two raka'at in congregation on Friday. The Prophet (saws) then migrated to Madinah, and after his stay at Quba on his way into Madinah, prayed his first Jumu'ah prayer at the area of the tribe of Banu Salamah (today, Masjid Qiblatain).

Answer (score 0):

Allah commanded in Quran,
"O you who have believed, when [the adhan] is called for the prayer on the day of Jumu'ah then proceed for to the remembrance of Allah and leave trade. that is better for you if you only knew. (surah Jumu'ah, verse 9)

RasulAllah (SAWS) said,
(performing) the Jumu'ah prayer in congregation is obligatory upon every muslim with four exception: a women, a boy, a slave and a sick person. (abu Dawood)

and there are many Ahadith that shows the virtues and significance of this day.